# Laravel 6 - dispatch event doesn't work (broadcast drive log)

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to start the work on broadcasting and event, but so far the event won't fire at all, and I don't have a clue what is going on

In my **.env** file I have this:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
```

Event class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrdersStatusUpdate implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('orders');
        // return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Events\OrdersStatusUpdate;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        OrdersStatusUpdate::dispatch();
    }
}
```

Nothing is happening when I fire a request in the browser (log is not created).

`I am running PHP 7.4.3 on localhost:9099`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan queue:work` to start your [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#running-the-queue-worker) and processing queue jobs. You can also use [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#supervisor-configuration) to automate this.

Comment: @sasha That and, if a queue worker is already running, you should check the `failed_jobs` table, perhaps the event broadcasting had an error thus it failed, had a similar issue and, errors that were occurring in the queued jobs weren't written to Laravel's logs but, could find them in the `failed_jobs` table instead.